# Citrix XenDesktop create an image to work across multiple hardware devices

Tags: citrix, image, xendesktop

I have created an image using this guide http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX119877.
However this only works for virtual and the model that I made the image on how can i extend compatibility to another device?
I am just using it for a vdisk that I can then also use as a virtual device but I wasnt the vdisk to be available over multiple devices.
Using Win 7 on the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from citrix stating that it is supposed to be done by using a common NIC and moving it to the other PC however this doesnt work when you have a Small form factor. The only way was to try and strip out the drivers from one device and inject them into the virtual disk.
I did not get this to work.